# A challenging graph theory problem that may not be so challenging for the right mind

Tags: graph-theory

Here is the question I am having trouble with and what I thought of it so far: There's nine people, let each person send a card to 3 others. Is it possible that each person receives 3 cards from the same 3 people to whom they sent cards?

Isn't this problem broken in the way it is designed or am I thinking it wrong? Technically, since there is no requirement of how many cards each student can receive, can't one student send a card out to three people and then those same three people send a card back to the student. Or is there another way to solve this then how would that be?

Comment: What you say makes sense, and then you try it out on paper. You should try to imagine nine people exchanging cards, and try to fit the situation in as much as you can. It will take you some time, but you will either see a problem eventually or things will work out.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hint, since the topic is graph theory.  Let each person be represented by a vertex, and draw an edge between two people if and only if those two people exchanged cards.  It follows that each vertex must be incident to exactly three edges--no more, no less.

To understand why, suppose $A$ and $B$ are distinct vertices/people.  If $A$ sent a card to $B$, then $B$ must have sent a card to $A$, otherwise $A$ did not receive a card from one of the recipients of $A$'s cards.  Similarly, if $A$ receives a card from $B$ but did not send a card to $B$, then $B$ has sent a card to $A$ but did not get a card from $A$ in return.  Therefore, each sending and receiving of cards must comprise an exchange of two cards between two people.  There cannot be any cases where a card is sent from one person to another, but no card is sent in the other direction.

With the above in mind, how many edges are in this graph?

Comment: Would there be 10 edges then?

Comment: @DeeJP If there are $9$ vertices, and each vertex has degree $3$, meaning there are $3$ edges drawn from each vertex, and each edge joins exactly $2$ vertices, how could you conclude there are only $10$ edges????  Draw it out.  Put $9$ dots on a piece of paper.  Try to draw lines between the dots so that there are $3$ lines from each dot.  Can you do it?  How many edges did you draw?

Comment: I can only draw 10 edges. If I add more edges then the degree of one of the vertices becomes 4.

Comment: Wait this time I did it I got 13 edges.